# Is there a way to gather slot-definition-readers from all the inheritance tree?

Tags: common-lisp, clos, mop

The generic function `slot-definition-readers` gets an argument that must be a `direct-slot-definition`. If an object is an instance of a class that inherits from another class how can I get hold of the readers of all the effective-slots of the object? Do I manually have to traverse the tree and call `slot-definition-readers` on the result of `class-direct-slots` in each superclass, gathering the results, or is there another way that I am not aware of?

Comment: I haven't seen such a thing in a library. It might exist. But for know it looks like you have to write it similar how you have described it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "community wiki" answer is here to provide an implementation of this feature. What follows uses no destructive operation (NCONC, MAPCAN) since an implementation might return an internal list without copying it. MAPPEND is imported from [alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html), and MOP operations can be imported from [closer-mop](http://www.crategus.com/books/closer-mop/).

```
(defun all-direct-slots (class)
  (append (class-direct-slots class)
          (mappend #'all-direct-slots
                   (class-direct-superclasses class))))

(defun all-slot-readers (class)
  (mappend #'slot-definition-readers
           (all-direct-slots class)))
```

Comment: `SLOT-DEFINITION-READERS` seems to return the actual list of readers (rather than a copy) on SBCL, so using it with mapcan kind of breaks things (try calling it twice on a subclass that both has a reader and inherits another). You should compose it with `COPY-LIST` to avoid problems.

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks a lot