# Is there a way to get the slots of a class?

Tags: class, common-lisp, slots, clos, lispworks

I have a class like this one

```
(defclass shape ()
 ((color :initform :black)
 (thickness :initform 1)
 (filledp :initform nil)
 (window :initform nil)))
```

Is there a function in common-lisp how to get a list of those slots if i only know instance of this class?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38452350/124319

Comment: Alright, thank you for answers. But i have another problem. I need to know every method from class. Even methods from inherited class. `(defclass point (shape) 
  ((x :initform 0) 
   (y :initform 0)))
` Is there a way, how to get it ?

Comment: See the linked question.

Comment: But I can not use any external libraries.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Many Common Lisp implementations support the CLOS *Meta-object Protocol*. This provides introspective operations for classes, slots and other *meta objects*.

In LispWorks the corresponding functions are directly accessible in the package `CL-USER`.

```
CL-USER 139 > (defclass shape ()
                ((color :initform :black)
                 (thickness :initform 1)
                 (filledp :initform nil)
                 (window :initform nil)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS SHAPE 40202910E3>

CL-USER 140 > (mapcar #'slot-definition-name
                      (class-direct-slots (class-of (make-instance 'shape))))
(COLOR THICKNESS FILLEDP WINDOW)
```

The functions `slot-definition-name` and `class-direct-slots` are defined by the Meta Object Protocol for CLOS and are supported in many Common Lisp implementations - just the package they are in may differ. In SBCL for example one might find them in the package `SB-MOP`.

From a class we can get the list of *direct slots*. Direct slots are the slots which are directly defined for that class and which are not inherited. If you want to get a list of all slots, then use the function `class-slots`.

*Slot* here means that we get a *slot definition* object, which describes the slot. To get the name of the slot, you have to retrieve the name from the slot definition object using the function `slot-definition-name`.

Comment: @Micky See also https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop. You can also use `(apropos 'slot-definition-name)` to find out in which packages those functions are defined in your implementation.

Comment: @coredump thanks, that helped me figure out how to run this on sbcl:

Comment: (mapcar #'sb-mop:slot-definition-name
          (sb-mop:class-direct-slots (class-of (make-instance 'shape))))