# LISP: Get all slot names from an class instance

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I need to make a window with the properties of a class (its slot-values).

It would be something like `describe` function.

My question is: How do I get all the slots-name for that class?

I wasn't able to find anything about it, only the `describe` function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40742048/5747548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
(mapcar #'slot-definition-name (class-slots class))
```

Comment: Yes. It works great.

Comment: See also https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop

Comment: This answer is incomplete and therefore should not have been tagged unless it was rectified and made standalone and comprehensive. The comment by jkiiski above referring to another stackoverflow answer is of acceptable quality.